# Getting back to the first activity via intent, what happens to the activity stack?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have an application which pulls data from a webserver, putting this data in a listview and then presenting it to the user. There are 4 activities involved, which can be called like this:

A -> B -> C -> D

or

A -> B -> D

Basically all the activities except A are pulling data from the web. Should there be any problems with the connection and there is a timeout coming up I want the activities B, C and D to inform the user and get back to A.

So what I did right now is, I set A to launch mode singleTask. This way I can catch the timeout exception and call a new intent starting A. But what happens to the activities in between? Let's say I am calling A->B->C->D and then in D the connection times out. Now the app is going back to A, but what about B and C? Does android automatically call onDestroy on these? What happens to the activity stack? Any hints appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you launch activity A, from activity D, set the intent flag:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
```

Using this flag will clear any activities in between A and the activity you are in, bringing A to the front. You also probably don't need to be using singleTask as a launch mode.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I am calling A->B->C->D and then in D the connection times out. Now the app is going back to A...

With your example, if all the child activities are launched with startActivityForResult() and activities B & C implement:

```
finishFromChild(Activity activity) {
    ...
    finish();
}
```

When activity D calls finish() after it has timed out, then each child will close in order (D -> C -> B -> A) with a chance to return any relevant data you might want to salvage.

Comment: If I use the finishFromChild() method there is a small problem. As soon as the finish() is called on D, it will get back to C and call onResume(). This is what I want to prevent as I create a thread in this method to pull the web data. There is no caching in the application as of now because the data can change rather quickly. So what I want is skip C and B and get right back to A and I don't care what happens to B and C.The only thing I want to know is what happens in the background if I do it via the singleTask call I did right now.